# Space Invaders IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm re-creating space invaders for a school project.

When trying to get the bullet to hit one of the enemies and add score I get the error

> IndexError: list index out of range.

Here's a simplified version of my game that recreates the problem:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import math

pygame.init()
FPS=30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((628, 602),0,32)

FILL=(0,162,232)
BLACK=(0,0,0)

font=pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',22)
mothership=pygame.image.load('mothership.png').convert()
mothership.set_colorkey(FILL)
bullet=pygame.image.load('bullet.png').convert()
player=pygame.image.load('player.png').convert()
player.set_colorkey(FILL)


def drawbullet(bulletx,bullety):
     screen.blit(bullet,(bulletx,bullety))
def drawplayer():
     screen.blit(player,(playerx,playery))
def drawmothership(mothershipx,mothershipy):
     screen.blit(mothership,(mothershipx,mothershipy))

bulletx=[]
bullety=[]
score=0
mothershipx=-30
mothershipy=200
playerx=84
playery=483
firing=False

while True:
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    drawplayer()
    drawmothership(mothershipx,mothershipy)
    mothershipx=mothershipx+7

    message=''+str(score)+''
    text=font.render(message,True,FILL)
    screen.blit(text,(143,59))

    if mothershipx>=628:
        mothershipx=-30
    for l in range(len(bulletx)):
        drawbullet(bulletx[l],bullety[l])
        bullety[l]=bullety[l]-10

    if math.hypot((bulletx[1]-mothershipx),(bullety[1]-mothershipy))<100:
        score=score+10


    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_LEFT] and playerx>0:
      playerx=playerx-5
    if keys[K_RIGHT] and playerx<583:
      playerx=playerx+5
    if event.type==KEYDOWN:
      if event.key==K_SPACE:
           firing=True
           firinglocationx=playerx+20
           bulletx.append(firinglocationx)
           bullety.append(483)
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace so we know which line in the code is getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to occur here :

```
if math.hypot((bulletx[1]-mothershipx),(bullety[1]-mothershipy))<100:
    score=score+10
```

you try to check if the second object of both arrays hits the concerning value of the motherships, but the list has zero elements at the beginning

Here is my solution :

```
for l in range(len(bulletx)):
    drawbullet(bulletx[l],bullety[l])
    bullety[l]=bullety[l]-10
    if math.hypot((bulletx[l]-mothershipx),(bullety[l]-mothershipy))<100:
        score=score+10
```

because if you have no elements in both lists, the for loop isnt  executed. And this checks for all elements, not only for the second.

And why so complicated ? How about creating a list of lists ?

Initiate a bullet list :

```
bullets=[]
```

Append a bullet if the player presses Space :

```
if event.type==KEYDOWN:
  if event.key==K_SPACE:
       firing=True
       firinglocationx=playerx+20
       bullets.append([firinglocationx,483})
```

Draw the bullet and check collision:

```
for bullet in bullets:
    drawbullet(bullet[0], bullet[1])
    bullet[1]=bullet[1]-1;
    if math.hypot((bullet[0]-mothershipx),(bullet[1]-mothershipy))<100:
        score=score+10
```

For a mothership with health, create a variable health :

```
mothershiphealth=100
```

That has to contain a couple of changes :

```
for l in range(len(bulletx)):
    drawbullet(bulletx[l],bullety[l])
    bullety[l]=bullety[l]-10
    if math.hypot((bulletx[l]-mothershipx),(bullety[l]-mothershipy))<100:
        score=score+10
        mothershiphealth-=10 #whatever damage you want
        bulletx.pop(l) #Delete bullet
        bullety.pop(l) #Delete bullet
```

Or, if you used only one list, as I suggested you'll need a variable count, to count the 'n object it is :

```
count=0;
for bullet in bullets:
    drawbullet(bullet[0],bullet0[1])
    bullet[1]=bullet[1]-10
    if math.hypot((bullet[0]-mothershipx),(bullet[1]-mothershipy))<100:
        score=score+10
        mothershiphealth-=10 #whatever damage you want
        bullet.pop(count) #Delete bullet
    count+=1;
```

And, to unblit the mothership :

```
if mothershiphealth > 0:
    drawmothership(mothershipx,mothershipy)
```

This only draws the Mothership if it has more health than zero

Comment: Thanks user7185318, that seemed to have worked for the most part. The only problem is that when the bullet hits the mothership it adds way more than 10 points because the mothership doesnt disappear when it gets hit. Is there any way to "unblit" the mothership after it gets hit by the bullet?

Comment: Yup that did it. Thanks for the help!